# Compare Camera captured images with computer generated images

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I am making an app which compare camera captured image with computer generated images and these images are stored in database.
I am using Opencv for image comparison but it only compare computer generated images correctly.When i capture same image with camera and compare that image with computer generated image then it does not match them acuurately.Is there any way where i can compare camera images also;

Here is my code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // Set image path
  String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
  String filename1 = path+"/images/266.jpg";
  String filename2 = path+"/images/20160805_121529.jpg";

  int ret;
  ret = compareFeature(filename1, filename2);

  if (ret > 0) {
   System.out.println("Two images are same.");
  } else {
   System.out.println("Two images are different.");
  }
 }

 /**
  * Compare that two images is similar using feature mapping  
  * @author minikim
  * @param filename1 - the first image
  * @param filename2 - the second image
  * @return integer - count that has the similarity within images 
  */
 public static int compareFeature(String filename1, String filename2) {
  int retVal = 0;
  long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

  System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

  // Load images to compare
  Mat img1 = Imgcodecs.imread(filename1, Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
  Mat img2 = Imgcodecs.imread(filename2, Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

  // Declare key point of images
  MatOfKeyPoint keypoints1 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
  MatOfKeyPoint keypoints2 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
  Mat descriptors1 = new Mat();
  Mat descriptors2 = new Mat();

  // Definition of ORB key point detector and descriptor extractors
  FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB); 
  DescriptorExtractor extractor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);

  // Detect key points
  detector.detect(img1, keypoints1);
  detector.detect(img2, keypoints2);

  // Extract descriptors
  extractor.compute(img1, keypoints1, descriptors1);
  extractor.compute(img2, keypoints2, descriptors2);

  // Definition of descriptor matcher
  DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);

  // Match points of two images
  MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();
//  System.out.println("Type of Image1= " + descriptors1.type() + ", Type of Image2= " + descriptors2.type());
//  System.out.println("Cols of Image1= " + descriptors1.cols() + ", Cols of Image2= " + descriptors2.cols());

  // Avoid to assertion failed
  // Assertion failed (type == src2.type() && src1.cols == src2.cols && (type == CV_32F || type == CV_8U)
  if (descriptors2.cols() == descriptors1.cols()) {
   matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2 ,matches);

   // Check matches of key points
   DMatch[] match = matches.toArray();
   double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

   for (int i = 0; i < descriptors1.rows(); i++) { 
    double dist = match[i].distance;
       if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
       if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
   }
   System.out.println("max_dist=" + max_dist + ", min_dist=" + min_dist);

      // Extract good images (distances are under 10)
   for (int i = 0; i < descriptors1.rows(); i++) {
    if (match[i].distance <= 10) {
     retVal++;
    }
   }
   System.out.println("matching count=" + retVal);
  }

  long estimatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
  System.out.println("estimatedTime=" + estimatedTime + "ms");

  return retVal;
 }
```

Here is pictures that i am comparing

[image]

And here is camera captured image

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you post examples of images you're trying to compare?

Comment: @Gabriel Ambrósio Archanjo i have updated my question

Comment: I also , going to do slimier thing like this,  are you find any thing please , help me also , 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58255425/is-it-possible-to-read-hidden-contentsteganography-using-android-camera-withou